# Type safety in Dart using Container

Tags: dart, type-safety

I found something strange in dart. If there is a list that contains instances of a base class (in this example Super), the list can be set with a list of inherited instances. It seems that this changes the list type at runtime.

Is this intended behavior or is this a bug in Dart?

```
abstract class Super {}

class A extends Super {}

class B extends Super {}

class Container {
List<Super> mylist = [];
Container(this.mylist);
}

void main() {
// 1. dont't works
final container = Container(<A>[A(), A()]);
// 2. works
final container = Container([A(), A()]);
print(container.mylist.runtimeType);

container.mylist.add(B());
print(container.mylist);
}
```

If case 1 is used in the code above I get the following error:

```
JSArray<A>
Uncaught Error: TypeError: Instance of 'B': type 'B' is not a subtype of type 'A'
```

The error is at the line where I try to add an instance of B:

```
container.mylist.add(B());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart has a system called [type promotion](https://www.raywenderlich.com/21955673-non-nullable-dart-understanding-null-safety#toc-anchor-018), where it can promote the type of a variable, similar to [type inference](https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system#type-inference).

It works as a *cast*. On the first example you've explicit promoted the type of your list to be of type `A`, so there's nothing strange about this.

Take a look at the first article that explains this mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```dart
final container = Container(<A>[A(), A()]);
```

you explicitly create a `List<A>` object.  Although `Container`'s constructor expects a `List<Super>`, it accepts a `List<A>` argument because Dart considers `Generic<Derived>` to be a subtype of `Generic<Base>` if `Derived` is a subtype of `Base`.  Your later attempt to do `container.mylist.add(B());` will fail because `container.mylist` is actually a `List<A>` and therefore cannot legally store any `B` elements.

When you instead do:

```dart
final container = Container([A(), A()]);
```

then, because the `List` literal is not given an explicit type, its type is inferred to be `List<Super>` from `Container`'s expected construction parameter. `container.mylist.add(B());` will succeed since `container.mylist` is actually a `List<Super>` and therefore can legally store `B` elements.